# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.appengine.api.utils.SystemProperty

Tags: jsp, google-app-engine

I am beginner in Google Cloud platform, I deployed my java web application using NetBeans 8.2 and i follow the tutorial on this [link](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/09/how-to-use-the-google-app-engine-with-the-netbeans-ide/). When i run the appengine, it returns:

"Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds."

when i check the error in Error Reporting in Google Cloud Platform:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/api/utils/SystemProperty
at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService (login_jsp.java:120)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service (HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle (ServletHolder.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1772)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter (JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1759)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle (ServletHandler.java:582)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle (ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle (SecurityHandler.java:524)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle (SessionHandler.java:226)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle (ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle (HandlerWrapper.java:134)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.ParseBlobUploadHandler.handle (ParseBlobUploadHandler.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle (ContextHandler.java:1182)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppEngineWebAppContext.doHandle (AppEngineWebAppContext.java:187)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope (ServletHandler.java:512)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope (SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope (ContextHandler.java:1112)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle (ScopedHandler.java:141)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle (AppVersionHandlerMap.java:293)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle (HandlerWrapper.java:134)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle (Server.java:539)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle (HttpChannel.java:333)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnection.handle (RpcConnection.java:213)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnector.serviceRequest (RpcConnector.java:81)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest (JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest (JavaRuntime.java:757)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest (JavaRuntime.java:720)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run (JavaRuntime.java:690)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run (JavaRuntime.java:882)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run (ThreadGroupPool.java:270)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
```

I put the jar files in Libraries that said in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/localunittesting).

what does it mean?
I just wan't to connect my Web Application in Google Cloud SQL and after i login, it returns 500 Server Error.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you give more details about it? what is the Cloud SDK version you are using?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I just downloaded the google cloud SDK, but its working now, I don't still know how it works but what I did is, I put SystemProperty in the code telling if I'm working on localhost, change the IP etc. of the database connection and if I'm running it in production, im connecting it to cloud sql, when i remove the SystemProperty in the code to deploy it in SDK it works, but I'm having a hard time to change it back if I'm working on localhost.